# Set Relativelayout height inside listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I want to set a `relativeLayout` height inside a `ListView.`

This is my code in `MenuListAdapter.java`

```
RelativeLayout background = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.background_color);
ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
txtTitle.setTypeface(typeface);
if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getType() == MenuType.HEADER)
{
     background.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.header_color));
     background.setClickable(false);
     background.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}else{
     background.setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);
}
```

I'm adding xml for more information of my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/background_color">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_layout_image"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_margin_text"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_margin_text"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_btn"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@drawable/menu_text"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_scrollview"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/notifTotal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_margin_text"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/radius_default"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/radius_default"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

but i get an error saying that `"E/AndroidRuntime(11406): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams"`

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code ? 
Thank's

It's working, use AbsListView instead of RelativeLayout.
Thank you for Mr.Piyush Kukadiya

Comment: can you post XML code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Change

```
background.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

to

```
background.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

**UPDATE :**

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and  `AbsListView.LayoutParams` are two different classes of `android.widget` Package.

Here you are replacing existing layout params of correct type `AbsListView.LayoutParams` with more generic `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` i.e. `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: Thank you mr piyush. It works. Can you explain to me why do i've to use AbsListView instead of RelativeLayout ?

Comment: So, that's the problem ? Thank you once again Mr. Piyush.
I'd like to upvote but since it's a new account. I've to reach 15 reputation.